# URL scheme to open Videos from a browser on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, url, video

I can create an link to an iBooks document using the "itms-books://book-name" URL scheme, use that link in an html anchor tag accessible via a browser. When I click the link, it launches iBooks and opens the document.

How can I create a similar link to launch the Videos app to play a specific video in my local library?  I've seen discussions about getting an asset URL from within another app, but I need something I can access via html in a browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just realized that the itms-books:// URL scheme does not open the book, it tries to find the book in the iTunes store. Now I need an answer for iBooks documents as well as Videos :-/

Answer (score 1):

There is videos:// which open the Videos Application, but I yet don't know how to use it. If I ever find something, I will let you know.